# Writing Output File Cuda C++

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I need to write simulation data computed on GPU into an output .csv file. Normally I would just use the fstream library but that's not possible on GPU.

Are there any built-in functions or other libraries that I could use to write data to .csv or .txt files directly from device code? Right now, performance is really not that important but rather an easy interim solution.

Comment: I doubt it.  What is wrong with reading the data back out of CUDA and outputting it normally?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to do direct file I/O in CUDA from device code, unless you are using something like [GPU Direct Storage (GDS)](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpudirect-storage/) (which most likely you are not, at the current time, and based on your question).  If you don't already have it set up, GDS might not be an "easy interim solution".

Copy the data to the host, then use whatever file I/O routines you are comfortable with.

Note that requests for library recommendations are specifically [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the printf statement to output the prints from Cuda kernel to a text file and then parse the text file to convert to CSV.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).